# java.lang.StackOverflowError in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark

Trying to run the example program from Spark 1.0.2
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.sql.RDDRelation --master local \spark-1.0.2-bin-hadoop1\lib\spark-examples-1.0.2-hadoop1.0.4.jar

the exception comes when the code tries to select on a table:-
sql("SELECT * FROM records").collect().foreach(println)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)

Answer (score 0):

A StackOverflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply. [see details.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html)

Have you increased the RDD size? or did any other change on the example code?

the original one example is incorporating just 100 records.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize((1 to 100).map(i => Record(i, s"val_$i")))
```

So, it's really weird you are getting a StackOverflowError with not changes on the source.

On the other hand, here you go, an [old reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/10931.html) about Scala StackOverflowError on compilation, in case, it can be related to the compiler itself.

> There are a number of reasons for such crash. I experienced such issue
>   in one of my programs:
>   http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.user/35292 I was using
>   the wrong construct (well, it was OK, but not suited to large lists).
>   I just searched "StackOverflow" in the subject lines of this mailing
>   list and found some similar cases (ie. SO in scalac, not at runtime,
>   of course), often by using large constructs (large array, large
>   expression...). This might or might not apply to your case, just FYI.